# How to get max(row_number) filtering on t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to filter max(row_number). But getting errors.
over partition by... order by code_description desc does not work for me. I have to get last code_id description. Right we can't keep aggregate function on where condition.I have imported records from excel

Help is much appreciated.

Expectation

Code_Id       Code_description
10000, Maintain healthy bone,teeth and increase immune

My code is:

```
Create table #test 
(
    code_id int,
    Code_description varchar(100)
)

insert into #test values (10000, 'Maintain healthy bone')
insert into #test values (10000, 'Maintain healthy teeth')
insert into #test values (10000, 'Increases Immune')
insert into #test values (10000, 'Maintain healthy bone,teeth and increase immune')

With cte as
(
    select 
        code_id, Code_description,
        row_number() over (partition by code_ID order by code_id) rn
    from 
        #test
)
select * 
from cte 
where rn = max(rn)
group by code_id, Code_description
```

Comment: "*I have to get last code_id description*" - do you have to get last code_id or do you have to get last Code_description?

Comment: Can you post what is the expected output?

Comment: I have to get max(rn) code_description

Comment: You can set a colum to generete auto incremental ID and filter like below:

    Create table #test 
    (
        code_id_flag int identity (1,1),
 code_id int,
        Code_description varchar(100)
    )

    insert into #test values (10000, 'Maintain healthy bone')
    insert into #test values (10000, 'Maintain healthy teeth')
    insert into #test values (10000, 'Increases Immune')

    With cte as
    (
 select * from  #test
    )
    select code_id, Code_description
    from cte 
    where code_id_flag = (SELECT MAX(code_id_flag) FROM #test)
    order by code_id_flag;